# Exercise on c ++

Tags: c++

(I apologize in advance for the spelling errors but everything has been translated with Google) Hello everyone I would need help with a code that should read two numbers and multiply between them using only add, subtract, multiply by 2 and divisions by two for each operation you define a function that performs it.
Obviously all using the subroutines.
I had an idea and below I am sending you the code string (there will be some written in Italian) but it gives me an error unknown to me or at least seen for the first time which would be: "[Error] ISO C ++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive] "
if anyone could help me i would be grateful. Now I'll write the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int leggidati()
{
    double n,m;
    cout<<"Dai n e m"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    cin>>m;
    return n,m;
}
    int moltiplicazione(int n,int m){
        double moltiplicazione;
        moltiplicazione=n*m;
        return moltiplicazione;
    }
    int divisione(int n,int m){
        int divisione;
        divisione=n/m;
        return divisione;
    }
    void risultati(double moltiplicazione, double divisione, int n, int m){
        cout<<"Il risultato della moltiplicazione è"<<moltiplicazione<<endl;
        cout<<"Il risultato della divisione è"<<divisione<<endl;
        
    }
    int main(void){
        int somma;
         for (somma = 0; somma <= moltiplicazione; somma += 2) {
        cout << somma << endl;
    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Why are you tagging with unrelated `javascript` and `C` language tags? I have removed them for you.

Comment: `somma <= moltiplicazione` What are you trying to do there? `moltiplicazione` is a function. Why are you comparing it with an `int`?

Comment: It also looks like you have a stray `}` at the end of your program. Note that you don't have to specify `void` in `int main(void)`. `int main()` will do just fine in C++.

Comment: Unrelated: I recommend reading up on what the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator) does. If you do it now you can save yourself some debugging later.

Comment: No stray `}`. Just a mistake in the indentation.

Comment: Looks like you want to call `moltiplicazione`, but you don't have any values to call it with yet. I fear you are missing some vital C++ fundamentals that will make this question very difficult to successfully answer, and once you've learned those fundamentals, will make the question unnecessary. I strongly recommend rereading the portion of your text book that covers functions.

Comment: `int` (`somma`) and `int (*)(int n, int m)` aka a function pointer  (`moltiplicazione`)  are incompatible types, try using some arguments in it ***i.e.*** `for (somma = 0; somma <= moltiplicazione(2, 3); somma += 2)`

Answer (score -2):

you are trying to return 2 values in function leggidati(). If you want to read 2 numbers and save them, you should use pointers. Here is example of correct code.

Here is working code for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int read_data(int *n, int *m){
    printf("Dai n e m:");
    scanf("%d", n);
    scanf("%d", m);
    return 0;
}

int mult(int n, int m){
    return (n * m);
}

double division(int n, int m){
    return (n / m);
}

void print_result(int n, int m){
    printf("Il risultato della moltiplicazione è: %d\n", mult(n, m));
    printf("Il risultato della divisione è: %.2f\n", division(n, m));       
}

int main(void){
    int n, m;
    read_data(&n, &m);
    print_result(n, m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Right idea, but this is a C answer to a C++ question.

Comment: I've given the answer which will help user to understand mistakes (calling functions with no arguments in     `void risultati`     and     `main`.   , etc.). The only part which seems to be more likely used in `C` rather than `C++` is using `printf` instead of `std::cin` and `std::cout`, which is not the point of the question at all. Very strange comment from you.